# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 : Crossing click fires 2 events : on button and element behind it

Tags: angular, events, click, focus, ionic2

Using Angular 2 on mobile (with ionic 2), I have a bug and I cannot find any similar issue so I need your help.

I have a textarea and an input above, when I click on the input, keyboard is appearing with an absolute block just above. In this block there is a button "close", when I click on it, it fires the hide() method to programmaticaly close the keyboard, this works well but after that, the keyboard appears with the focus in textarea. (the "close" button is over the textarea).

It seems like tapping on the close button is going through it and also tap on the textarea.

[image]

On the image it's the red button. When i click on it, the keyboard close and the textarea just behind is focus, does anyone know why ?

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

Close button code :

```
  public hide(){
      Keyboard.close();
  }
```

Html of the block :

```
<ion-grid class="keyboard-accessory">
     <ion-row>
       <ion-col width-80>
         <button ion-button tappable clear class="cancel" (tap)="hide()"> <ion-icon ios="ios-close" md="md-close"></ion-icon></button>
         <input id="keyboardInput" #keyboardInput [(ngModel)]="text" (ngModelChange)="changeInputValue()" type="text"/>
         <p id="keyboardTitle"></p>
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col width-20>
         <button ion-button clear class="accept" (click)="validate()">Validate</button>
       </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

I forgot to say that the block is inside the ion-footer, and the textarea in the ion-content, so there is no bubbling effect.
Using stopPropagation or preventDefault does not work.

Comment: can you add the code of the close button as well as the html

Comment: have you tried stoppropagation?

Comment: Yes i tried it, but as i said, this is not a bubbling effect, they are not in the same DOM tree, so it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease size of text area with css , or 
autosize it using
" npm install ionic2-autosize ".

Comment: This could be the solution but I still don't understand why 1 tap activates 2 events